# Django, data forms cannot be saved

Tags: django

I have a problem with Django when I would like to get information from the register. I can get their first name, last name, and email but no nickname and graduated schools. I thought i did it correctly since i added nickname and school inside forms.py

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile



class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    nickname = forms.CharField()
    school = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2',
                 'first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname', 'school']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    nickname = forms.CharField()
    school = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname', 'school']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get['username']
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

I have tried to save by adding form.cleaned_data.get in views.py but it still didn't work. I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not saving "nickname" and "graduated schools" to any model(based on models.py). First of all, you are inheriting from the user model when you do the following:

'''
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

'''

In doing so you can only save what you have in the Profile model and the User model, which I would recommend reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/ detailing what does the User model have(username,password, etc.).

Lastly, I would just add the nickname and the graduated schools to the Profile Model and it should work.

Comment: Thx you, i solved it by adding those into my Profile